# Separating a 2d Array into Regions

Tags: java, arrays

I want to separate a 2D Array into 4 regions. I already did it with a 5x5 array. Is it possible to do it with a 10x10? I've been scratching my head for the past 5 hours. Here's my 5x5:

```
char array1 [][] = new char [5][5];

    for(int k = 0; k < array1.length; k++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array1[k].length; j++)
        {
            array1[k][j] = 'E';

            System.out.print(array1[k][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.print("|" + " ");


        for(int j = 0; j < array1[k].length; j++)
        {
            array1[k][j] = 'E';

            System.out.print(array1[k][j] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    int line = 1;
    while(line<=22){System.out.print('-'); line++;}
    System.out.println();

    for(int k = 0; k < array1.length; k++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array1[k].length; j++)
        {
            array1[k][j] = 'E';

            System.out.print(array1[k][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.print("|" + " ");

        for(int j = 0; j < array1[k].length; j++)
        {
            array1[k][j] = 'E';

            System.out.print(array1[k][j] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

I even tried using an enhanced for loop but that got things even more complicated.

Sorry I wasn't clear enough. What I meant is, the code that I posted already gave an output that I wanted. But I was wondering whether I could get the same output with a 10x10 2D array. (a 10x10 2D array, separated into 4 regions with each region being 5x5)

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "divide a 2D array into 4 regions". As far as I can see, all your code is doing is printing out a 11x22 grid with half the space being empty

Answer (score 0):

your code works just fine. Change:

```
array1[5][5]
```

by

```
array1[10][10]
```

and

```
while(line<=22){System.out.print('-'); line++;}
```

by

```
while (line <= (array1[0].length*2+1)*2){System.out.print('-'); line++;}
```

As you say you searched 5 hours on this, I think you have to be more clear on the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just print pretty image divided to four part, as your code does, you can use that code:

```
int size = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) {
    if (i == size) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= size * 4; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size * 2; j++) {
        if (j == size) System.out.print("| ");
        System.out.print("E ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

And change variable 'size' to whatever size you need.